# Find generating function

Tags: co.combinatorics

Define  a  transformation $T_s$ of integer sequence $\{ a_n \}$  by 
$$
b_n=T_s(a_n)={n \choose s} \sum_{i=s}^{n-1} \frac{a_i}{{i \choose s}}, 
$$
for a fixed $s \in \mathbb{N}.$

For instance, if we  aplly  the transformation $T_2$  to the sequence $a_n=1$  then we get the sequence $b_n=n(n-2).$
Maple code for  the sample

```
    T:=(a,s)->factor(simplify(product(n-i,i=0..s-1)*sum(a(k)/product(k-i,i=0..s-1),k=s..n-1)));
a:=n->1:T(a,2);
                                 n(n-2)
```

**Question.** Suppose that $a_n$ has a  generating function (ordinary or  exponential or another one) $a(x).$ What is the generating function of transformed sequence?

Comment: Judging from the code, I think you want $${n \choose s} \sum_{i=s}^{n-1} \frac{a_i}{i \choose s}$$

Comment: Sorry. Yes,  of cource.

Comment: Can you do the case $s=0$ ... $b_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$ ?? How about the case $s=1$ ... $b_n = n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i/i$ ??

Comment: @Gerald
Yes,  for  the first case $s=0$ the generation function is 
${\frac {z}{ \left( 1-z \right) ^{2}}}$. For  the case s=1    the  is not elementary function and  for  the  case $s=2$ I have  got 
$$
{\frac {z(-1+3\,z)}{ \left( 1-z \right) ^{3}}}.
$$

Comment: I think Gerald was talking about general $a_n$.  The ordinary generating function of $b_n$ in the case $s=1$ is, I think,
$$b(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \int_0^x \frac{a(t)}{t}\ dt + \frac{x a(x)}{1-x}$$

Comment: (this is assuming $a_0 = 0$)

Comment: In the general case  we  may assume  that $a_s=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done step by step.
First note that $\binom{n}{s}/\binom{i}{s}$ can be written as $n(n-1)\cdots(n-s+1)/i(i-1)\cdots(i-s+1)$
Since we have the generating function (with assuming $a_i=0$ for $i< s$)
$$a(x)x^{-s}=\sum_{i=s}^{\infty} a_ix^{i-s}$$
We obtain the following by integrating $s$ times.
Let $A_0(x)=a(x)x^{-s}$, and $A_{k+1}(x)= \int_0^x A_k(t)dt$.
Then 
$$A_s(x)=\sum_{i=s}^{\infty} a_i\frac{x^i}{i(i-1)\cdots (i-s+1)}$$
The generating function for $b_n/ n(n-1)\cdots (n-s+1)$ can be obtained from the product
$$\left(\sum_{i=s}^{\infty} a_i\frac{x^i}{i(i-1)\cdots (i-s+1)}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x^j\right)$$

Now the generating function for $b_n$ follows from differentiating s times
Again assuming $b_i =0$ for $i< s$, we have
$$B_0(x)= A_s(x) \frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$B_{k+1}(x)=\frac{d}{dx} B_k(x)$$
$$\sum_{n=s}^{\infty} b_n x^n = B_s(x) x^s$$

Comment: Thanks. I have  got similar result
$$
\sum_{n=s}^{\infty} b_n x^n=x^s \frac{d^s}{dx^s}\left( \frac{x}{1-x} \underbrace{\int_0^x \cdots \int_0^x}_{s \text{    times}} \frac{a(x)}{x^s} \underbrace{dx \cdots dx}_{s \text{    times}} \right).
$$